# Generate and save plots from rows of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, row

Python newbie here.

My problem is the following. I have this (80, 1002) DataFrame of continuous data loaded from a .csv file. My goal with it is to go through every row of this df (80) and plot each row on a basic pyplot.plot. In this df, the first 2 columns are to be used as title so that each plot has it's specific name (here it's the time of the recording and the name of the electrode).

What I did to plot one row is :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
Location = r'/pathtothefile/name.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(Location,sep=';')
time=range(1,1001);

plt.plot(time,df.loc[0, "0":"999"],'g')
plt.axhline(0, color='black',linewidth=0.5)
plt.xlabel('Time (ms)')
plt.ylabel('Power (mV)')
plt.axis([1, 1000, -5, 5])
plt.title(str(df.iloc[0,0]) + str(df.iloc[0,1]))
plt.show()
row.savefig('/pathwheretosave/name.eps',
        format='eps', dpi=1000)
```

The "time" variable is to be plotted with the rows data. From here I want to loop on the rows of a data frame and plot/save each row in a separated file but so far : I failed. Any idea on how to do that ?
Ideally I want to write the title of the plot in the name of the file to be saved.

Comment: You should directly plot your data from `pandas`. It also uses matplotlib to plot. I don't remember the exact syntax, but it's something like `df.plot(x=<column_name_to_use>, y=<column_name_to_use>)`. See the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? It will get a little more complicated if you want your x-axis to use time, rather than timestamp-labels, but it sounds like you are taking 1 measurement per second, across your electrodes.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make a sample DataFrame
ts = datetime.datetime.now()
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [ts, ts, ts, ts],
              'electrode': [1, 2, 3, 4],
              1: [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
              2: [0.22, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
              3: [0.37, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]}, 
              columns = ['time', 'electrode', 1, 2, 3] )

number_of_measurements = df.shape[1] - 2

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
    df.iloc[i][2:].plot(ax=ax, xticks=range(1, number_of_measurements + 1, 1))
    plot.set_xlabel("Time (ms)")
    plot.set_ylabel("Power (mV)")
    fig.suptitle('{} electrode:{}'.format(df.iloc[i].time, df.iloc[i].electrode))
    fig.savefig('plot{}-{}.png'.format(df.iloc[i].time, df.iloc[i].electrode), bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Hi ! Ok, I touched it up a little to fit everything to my code and it gave me the 80 different plot I wanted ! Still need to figure out how to do for the title so that I actually know which plot is for which row, and figure out how to save everything BUT, this is a huge step ! Thanks you

Comment: I edited the answer to include the title in the plot. You might also want to play with the timestamp formatting, to get the accuracy you want. Feel free to mark the question as answered if you are happy.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to loop each row. This can be achieved by using the [itertuple](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) method as follows.

Example data:

```
sales = [{'values': [1,2,3,4], 'title': 'title 1'},
         {'values': [2,3,5,7], 'title': 'title 2'},
         {'values': [4,5,5,7], 'title': 'title 3'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
```

Produce a plot for the values in each row with the title specified in each row

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    plt.plot(row.values,marker='o')
    plt.title(row.title)
    plt.savefig(row.title + '.png')
    plt.clf()
```

The output of this is 3 separate plots (one for each row in the dataframe).